# Assign a set of strings to contents of a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector named `months` that contains the numbers 1-12 over and over. These numbers are read from a file. How would i be able to make it so that in this specific vector the number 1 = "January", 2 = "February", 3 = "March" ect so that when using cout << months[3] << endl; it would output "March" for example instead of the integer it is?.

Comment: Store strings rather than integers? Or is there more to the situation than you've described?

Comment: I'm reading the numbers from a file into a integer, but then when using cout i would like the actual name of the month to be displayed rather than the number. @MikeSeymour

Comment: Use a map with an int, string combination.

Comment: It still sounds like you just want a vector of strings.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a lot more sense to me to use a constant array of month names and access those when necessary. The indices stored in `months` range from 1 to 12, so we'll need to subtract 1 from the index to access the correct month:

```
std::string month_names[] = {
    "January",
    "February",
    // ...
};

// ... Get the month indices from a file ...

std::cout << month_names[months[3] - 1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: If you add a dummy value as the first item in the array, you won't have to subtract 1 from the index. :-)

Comment: The age-old problem of optimizing for memory or speed. In this case it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a `std::map` to associate a number with a string.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> Month = {{1,"January"}, {2,"February"}, {3,"March"} /* etc */ };
   cout << Month[3] << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
March
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/oMgN4z

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to define an array of string literals with month names and use the elements of the vector as indices for this array. For example

```
const char *month_name[] = 
{ 
    "January", "February", "March", /*...*/ "December" 
};

std::cout << month_name[ months[i] - 1] << std::endl;
```

Or

```
const char *month_name[] = 
{ 
    "", "January", "February", "March", /*...*/ "December" 
};

std::cout << month_name[ months[i] ] << std::endl;
```

where months[i] is an element of the vector with index i.

Comment: Wow, you didn't use a dummy value as the first entry.  The dummy value removes the requirement to subtract 1 from the index.